# Sitecore performance Testing - IIS not responding

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, sitecore, response

Here is my scenario. we have a web page (physical file) deployed in SiteCore. The page calls an Item which is bound to a layout / Sub Layout. We are placing a HTTP call to the item using httpwebclient. This is to make use of the HTML cache based on the query string parameter.

Every thing worked great except for one scenario. **We are trying to do a load test with 70 concurrent threads. Threads are ramped up by 2 every second until it gets to 70. loop count of 500**

The behavior I see is that within first minute we are getting a huge latency of about 45 seconds for few requests. **after this 45 seconds, every thing is normal** and the server serves better. At the end, the test was 100% pass and an average response time of 600 ms.

**Throughout the test, the CPU usage was well within 70% (mostly 30-40)**

Now the concern is that there are few requests which got response in 45 seconds. this will be a time out scenario when i have it integrated with other system.

Below is my configuration:
Sitecore Version: 6.4.1
OS: Windows 7 
RAM 8Gb 
Processor: Dual with 4 cores each

I also tried removing the HTTP call from my page to item and make use of DotNet cache to hold the response. This time the response was healthy with only few calls going to 5 seconds.

Should i enable or disable any settings in Sitecore to allow this sudden spike in load?

Comment: Did you have a read through the [Performance Tuning Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/cms_tuning_guide_sc60-66-a4.pdf) and [Recommended Practices](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sitecore_recommended_practices-a4.pdf)

Comment: Are you having sitecore start from cold? Because the first minute might just be sitecore spinning up and hydrating its caches.

Comment: yes @jammykam, i did go thru it. i just got this resolved by setting the web garden and allowing IIS to serve more concurrent requests.

Comment: @IvanL: the problem is seen even when Sitecore is up. Mostly i see this problem when the count of concurrent users is increased more than 30 with 500 requests from each